# How to rotate the results in a board made of lists?

Tags: python-3.5

I'm trying to learn how to code with Python and I have tried this exercise in which I have to rotate this board by 90° degrees but I dont get how. Thanks for the help.

```
numlist = [1,3,0,2]
board = [[0, 0, 0, 0],
         [1, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 2],
         [0, 3, 0, 0]]
```

I use this to print a table when it is given a numlist:

```
def ctcb(numlist):   # Create The Chess Board 
    n = 0
    board = []
    the_len = len(numlist)
    for i in range(the_len): # create a list with nested lists
        board.append([])      
        for n in range(the_len):
            board[i].append(0) # fills nested lists with data
    while n < len(board):
        for x,y in enumerate(numlist):  
            board[y][x] = y
            n += 1
    # print(board)
    for e in board:
        print(e)
```

the result should be this one:

```
board = [[0, 0, 2, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 3],
         [0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `zip(*board)` to transpose the board, and then use `reversed` to get the reverse of that transpose.

```
board = [[0, 0, 0, 0],
         [1, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 2],
         [0, 3, 0, 0]]
print([list(x) for x in reversed(list(zip(*board)))])
# [[0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 3], [0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: oh, ok thanks I've never heard of the zip function. Thanks a lot.